# Is there any gcc compiler primitive for "svc"?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cortex-m

I'm working on writing a program running on Cortex-m3.

At first I wrote an assembly file which executes 'svc'.

```
svc:
    svc 0
    bx lr
```

I decided to use gcc's inline asm, so I wrote it as follows, but the `svc` function was not inlined.

```
__attribute__((naked))
int svc(int no, ...)
{
    (void)no;
    asm("svc 0\n\tbx lr");
}

int f() {
    return svc(0,1,2);
}

------------------ generated assembly ------------------
svc:
    svc 0
    bx lr
f:
    mov     r0, #0
    mov     r1, #1
    mov     r2, #2
    b       svc
```

I guess it's not inlined since it is `naked`, so I dropped the `naked` attribute and wrote like this.

```
int svc(int __no, ...)
{
    register int no asm("r0") = __no;
    register int ret asm("r0");
    asm("svc 0" : "=r"(ret) : "r"(no));
    return ret;
}

------------------ generated assembly ------------------
svc:
    stmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
    ldr     r0, [sp]
    add     sp, sp, #16
    svc 0
    bx      lr
f:
    mov     r0, #0 // missing instructions setting r1 and r2
    svc 0
    bx      lr
```

Although I don't know why gcc adds some unnecessary stack operations, `svc` is good. The problem is that `svc` is not inlined properly, the variadic parameters were dropped.

Is there any `svc` primitive in gcc? If gcc does not have one, how do I write the right one?

Comment: inlined functions must be declared in the header file (implementation must be available at compile time), which I'm guessing you aren't doing because you haven't marked the function "inline" (and thus would get already defined errors when combining compilation units)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Both were defined in the same compilation unit. Even if they're not, it can be inlined if link time optimization is used. The `inline` keyword is not the solution here I guess.

Comment: it is SO much easier to just write an assembly language function and assemble and link it than to deal with compiler specific inline asm nuances.   svc takes an immediate argument so you will not be able to pass an argument and have that be the svc immediate unless you use self modifying code.

Comment: You could use something like `#define svc asm volatile ("svc 0")` to create a wrapper for SVC. You can't omit volatile in such cases.

Comment: @dwelch Writing an assembly function seems not quite different from writing a naked function. Currently EABI for linux also uses svc 0 with syscall number in r7, so the immediate part will not be an issue for it.

Comment: @auselen Defining it is actually is the same with the non-naked version of svc i wrote.

Comment: It seems that I didn't explain the problem precisely. :( What I exactly want is to tell gcc not to optimize out the ellipsis part of the function.

Comment: Please clarify your problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro like this.

```
#define __svc(sNum) __asm volatile("SVC %0" ::"M" (sNum))
```

And use it just like any compiler-primitive function, `__svc(2);`.

Since it is just a macro, it will only generate the provided instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the syntax that is used in `core_cmFunc.h` which is supplied as part of the ARM CMSIS for the Cortex-M family. Here's an example that writes a value to the Priority Mask Register:

```
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static inline void __set_PRIMASK(uint32_t priMask)
{
  __ASM volatile ("MSR primask, %0"::"r" (priMask));
}
```

However, creating a *variadic* function like this sounds difficult.